# Natbib: Truncate list of authors ONLY in the citation

Tags: natbib

(After a long series of searchs in vain):
For a citation where authors list is greater or equal to **`3`** I want to display `First_author et al` ONLY in the citation and NOT in the bibliographic entry.  Is that possible please ?

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Authors text cited~\citep{Meliker2010}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnatcustom}
\bibliography{MyBiblio}
\end{document}
```

Here the `MyBiblio.bib` file:

```
@incollection{Meliker2010,
author={Meliker, Jaymie R. and Slotnick, Melissa J. and AvRuskin, Gillian A. and Kaufmann,  Andrew M. and Jacquez, Geoffrey D. and Nriagu, Jerome O.},
year={2010},
booktitle={Handbook of Applied Spatial Analysis},
editor={Fischer, Manfred M. and Getis, Arthur},
title={Exposure Assessment in Environmental Epidemiology},
publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
pages={753-767},
}
```

Note that the `plainnatcustom.bst` file is a renamed copy of the known `plainnat.bst` file where I replaced inside the `"and"` by `"et"` (to get translation of **and** to **et** in french) and put it in my LaTeX working directory.

For this MWE I get the citation as:
- Authors text cited **(Meliker, Slotnick, AvRuskin, Kaufmann, Jacquez, et Nriagu, 2010)**.

But I look for a citation display like this:
- Authors text cited **(Meliker et al. 2010)**.

No problem with the bibliographic entry where full list of authors is displayed as I do prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the "normal" truncation behavior for citation callouts to pieces with three or more author, you should *not* specify the option `longnamesfirst` when loading the `natbib` package. Instead, type

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: All right, I didn't expect the solution will be so simple :) But what about the fixed number of authors to truncate which is 3 in my case ?

Comment: @Houssem - I'm not sure how to interpret your follow-up question: Are you looking to change the current truncation criterion (currently: 1 or 2 -- no truncation; 3 or more -- truncation) to something different?

Comment: No, I think you've answered my question. I want to truncate for more than 3 authors. So this should get the correct display I need. Thanks!